# How to create the layout for android as on image?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

How to create the layout for android as on image?

[image: layout image]

I try next code:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="kkkkddd"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/text_email" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/prompt_email"
            android:id="@+id/text_label_email"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/text_email" />
        ...
```

but `label_email` is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your label-TextView first and set for it fixed width. Than place value-TextView to right of label:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/prompt_email"
        android:id="@+id/text_label_email"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="kkkkddd"
        android:toRightOf="@id/text_label_email"
        android:id="@+id/text_email" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Linear layout with orientation as horizontal :)

Comment: Same question: how to align all tv to one vertical line as on image?

Comment: Place all these Linearlayouts in an outer Linearlayout with orientation as vertical.

Comment: and add `android:gravity="right" in first tv. Ok. But but nested layouts is bad for performance. Answer with RelativeLayout is better.

Answer (score 0):

Imo a LinearLayout would fit better for this purpose. For instance:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orienation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="kkkkddd"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/text_email" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/prompt_email"
        android:id="@+id/text_label_email"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/text_email" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and you could do this for each pair

Comment: How to align all tv to one vertical line as on image?

Answer (score 0):

make parent Linearlayout. And the use inner linearLayouts. In innerlayouts give gravity horizontal. then give .5 weight to its both childs i.e for "Email" textview & "utkin@gmail.com" weight should be .5 for both. set right alignment  for "Email" and set left alignment for "utkin@gmail.com".

It will work perfectly.

Voteup or mark true if helpful

Comment: Yes, it works. But answer with RelativeLayout better.